# How to remove the duplicates from the Data frame only if that occur with in 5 days

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to remove the duplicates from a dataframe grouping by id and sub-id that occurred within 5 days from its previous occurrence.

input:

[image]

output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) for compare datetimes per both columns and remove if less like `5` days:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df1 = df[~df.groupby(['id','sub_id'])['Date'].diff().dt.days.lt(5)]
```